# IE10 developer tools popped out. How to bring back in window?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, ie-developer-tools

The Internet Explorer 10 developer tools popped out in a separate window when I clicked `Start Debugging`.

I can't find how to bring the developer tools back into the same window as the page I'm troubleshooting.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Click the icon on the right hand side of the menu bar, or press `Ctrl+P`.

Comment: I should've seen that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning @ndm's comment into community answer:

- Click the icon on the right hand side of the menu bar
- Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.